# AWS Cognito - User based S3 folder access testing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

Currently I am working on an application where I need to provide folder specific user access on S3 location to the logged in AWS Cognito users.

To start with simplest approach, I am currently trying to access S3 bucket through JavaScript code.
I am facing a CORS related exception while accessing the S3 bucket through JavaScript code. The exception that I am getting is

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/' from origin 'http://10.1.2.3' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`

The authentication is working successfully, however facing challange while s3 access.

**S3 Access policy**

`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowGroupToSeeBucketListInTheConsole",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}`

The required JavaScript code that I am using here is given below

```
function signInButton() { 

var bucketName = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/my-s3-bucket';
var IdentityPoolId = 'us-east-1:705a3b3c-6d6e-4abc-8de9-4275fghi8798b';

var authenticationData = { 
    Username : document.getElementById("inputUsername").value, 
    Password : document.getElementById("inputPassword").value, 
}; 

var authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData); 

var poolData = { 
    UserPoolId : _config.cognito.userPoolId, 
    ClientId : _config.cognito.clientId, 
}; 

var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData); 

var userData = { 
    Username : document.getElementById("inputUsername").value, 
    Pool : userPool, 
}; 

var cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData); 

var authToken = null;

cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, { 
    onSuccess: function (result) { 
        var accessToken = result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken(); 
        document.getElementById("loginsuccess").innerHTML = "Login successful"; 
    }, 

    onFailure: function(err) { 
        alert(err.message || JSON.stringify(err)); 
    }, 
}); 

var cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();

if (cognitoUser != null) {
    cognitoUser.getSession(function(err, result) {
        if (result) {
            console.log('You are now logged in.', result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());

            // Add the User's Id Token to the Cognito credentials login map.
            AWS.config.update({
                region: _config.cognito.region,
                credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
                    IdentityPoolId: IdentityPoolId,
                    Logins: {
                        'cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_wDPj8XHj2': result.getIdToken().getJwtToken()
                    }
                })
            });
        } else {
            console.log('Error while authentication');
        }
    });
}


var s3 = new AWS.S3({
    apiVersion: '2006-03-01', 
    params: {Bucket: bucketName}
});

s3.listBuckets(function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
    } else {
        console.log("Success", data.Buckets);
    }
});
```

}
Thanks in advance for your help.

Avinash.

Comment: Also, I tried to modify the S3 CORS permissions.

Comment: Some how I am able to access the S3 bucket by using listObjects instead of listBuckets. However, when I am trying to access the user specific bucket by using ${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub} into the IAM policyfor Resource variable, I am not able to do this and I am getting AccessDeniad error while doing listObjects and putObject method of S3 in javascript.

Comment: how did you get ${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub} in code?